# What is the font of this "p"?

Tags: fonts

I'm typing a document using LaTeX. But the font of the "p" in the inequality $depth(M)\leq dim(A/p)$ (as in the following picture) is completely unknown to me.

[image]

**Question:** How do you type this "p" in latex?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `\wp`............

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That works, thank you!

Comment: [DeTeXify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) properly identifies this symbol. Also, see [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/125871).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the comment of @DavidCarlisle, this is `\wp`.